# Sqlite3 and Python: Handling a locked database

Tags: python, sqlite

I sometimes run python scripts that access the same database concurrently. This often causes database lock errors. I would like the script to then retry ASAP as the database is never locked for long.

Is there a better way to do this than with a `try` `except` inside a `while` loop and does that method have any problems?

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me... Of course, if you're doing stuff that needs concurrent access then you should consider something different than sqlite3 of course...

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `timeout` parameter in your calls to the [connect function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

```
db = sqlite3.connect("myfile.db", timeout = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for concurrency, SQlite is not the answer. The engine doesn't perform good when concurrency is needed, especially when writing from different threads, even if the tables are not the same.
If your scripts are accessing different tables, and they have no relationships at DB level (i.e. declared FK's), you can separate them in different databases and then your concurrency issue will be solved.
If they are linked, but you can link them in the app level (script), you can separate them as well.
The best practice in those cases is implementing a lock mechanism with events, but honestly I have no idea how to implement such in phyton.